# UTC timezone when installing Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, time

I prefer to have all my boxes set to UTC.

When installing Ubuntu 16.04 using netboot, I don't get offered the UTC timezone anymore. Under "Choose Language" there's no "etc", just the usual continents - America, Europe, and so on. When I get to the "Configure the Clock" step, "UTC" isn't listed, and I'm told to go back and change my territory if I want a different timezone. But none of the territories seem to offer UTC.

How do I set the clock to UTC from the get-go?

Comment: By "netboot", do you mean `mini.iso`, or PXE, or what?

Comment: Won't Europe/Greenwich give UTC?

Comment: By "netboot" I mean the images under http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/ - here, in particular, for xen.

Comment: @Bharadwaj Raju Ubuntu 16.04 LTS does not seem to offer me "Greenwich" under "Europe", at least not if started with the netboot images.

Comment: Also, to the person who posted an "answer" and presumably downvoted the question when I said "changing the timezone after install is only a workaround": I have one reputation, this is a throwaway account. You only hurt yourself by voting down a legitimate question (which costs you one rep, whereas I'm not losing any). That, and you make the community look bad, and deprive Ubuntu of the possibility for documenting where the option to set the time to UTC (or Greenwich for that matter) in the installer has gone.

Comment: For what it's worth; this is [launchpad bug 1582865](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debian-installer/+bug/1582865). If you want it fixed mark the bug as affecting you.